# Bottom align a floated div. ( image )

Tags: html, css

This seemed simple in my head.. But it's not.  I have 2 div's. floating next to eachother
The right div should have an image that is **always sticking to the footer**

It's not even applying the 100% Height of my .block div, the parent div ( body ) is also set at 100%

For some reason this is not working with my following code.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ELtaN/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
    Header
</div>

<div class="block">
    <img src="http://www.zwaldtransport.com/images/placeholders/placeholder1.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;   
    background: url('background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}


.header {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    background: red;
}

.block {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}

.block img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused... What do you want the page to look like? Write your question again but make it easy to read and understand..

Comment: Remove the `float:left;` from `.header` class.

Comment: If its not getting the height for the body try using `html, body` then all the css you had for `body` under that.

Comment: The .block div should be on the bottom.. While it still floats next to the .header div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. check and let me know, have you asked for this:

```
.header {
height: 100%;
width: 40%;
background: red;
}

.block {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width: 60%;
height: auto;
background: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi, When using your code, the .block div doesn't float right anymore, It is positioned underneath the .header div.. I'm looking for a way to have the .block div at the bottom but still floating next to the .header :) and thanks!

Comment: Add `float:right;` in the `.block` class. And about the bottom how it is showing, is it perfect ?

Comment: Glad to know your problem is solved. Ok. Upvote and mark the answer accepted please. Thanks.